# Y Axis error in Jqplot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I'm new with using jqPlot but `y` axis (money number) is showing too high.
My data is `$5000`, `$2000`, `$10000`, and `$1000`. Meanwhile `y` axis shows numbers in millions.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bulan = <?php echo $bulan;?>;
    var maxDay = <?php echo $maxDay;?>;
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($all_data) ?>;
    var arr = new Array(maxDay);
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(2);
        arr[i][0] = data[i]['tanggal'];
        arr[i][1] = data[i]['harga'];
    }
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart2', [arr], {
        title: 'Data Bulan ' + bulan,
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%b&nbsp;%#d'
                } 
            },
            yaxis: {
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString:'%.2f'
                }
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 2
        },
        cursor: {
            show: false
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the render:

[image]

Comment: @set max value in yaxis

Comment: Plz write your solution in answer so its helpful to other, Or delete your own question